# How to replace value in list of list that matched with list of keyword string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have list of article, title, and keyword contains this word:

```
article = ['JAKARTA, KOMPAS.com – PT Hino Motors Sales Indonesia (HMSI) merilis truk baru yaitu FLX260 JW, Selasa (6/4/2021). Truk ini memiliki konfigurasi sumbu 8x2 atau biasa disebut dengan trinton.\n\nMemiliki empat sumbu roda, tentu truk terbaru Hino ini bisa mengangkut beban yang besar, FLX260 JW memiliki GVW 32 ton. Namun perlu diperhatikan, jangan sampai truk terbaru ini malah dijadikan truk yang Over Dimension Over Loading (ODOL).\n\nDirektur Jenderal Perhubugan Darat Kemeterian Perhubungan Budi Setiadi mengatakan, Hino meluncurkan kendaraan yang dikatakan memiliki kekuatan lebih tapi efisien. Ini menjadi suatu tantangan bagi karoseri.\n\nBaca juga: Masalah Lain Truk ODOL Indonesia, Ditolak Masuk Negara Tetangga\n\nKOMPAS.com/STANLY RAVEL Ilustrasi truk ODOL di jalan tol. KOMPAS.com/STANLY RAVEL Ilustrasi truk ODOL di jalan tol.\n\n“Karena begitu bicara kekuatan, dia (pembeli) mengira bisa dipasang apa saja. Hal ini dikarenakan pembeli didominasi orang yang enerjik dan penuh inovasi dan kreasi. Jangan sampai kreasi mereka menciptakan truk-truk ODOL baru,” ucap Budi dalam acara peluncuran produk terbaru Hino beberapa waktu lalu.\n\nBudi berharap, ke depan, tidak ada lagi karoseri yang membuat truk over dimension untuk mengangkut beban berlebih (over loading). Selain itu juga berharap dari Hino untuk sama-sama menjaga Indonesia bebas truk ODOL.\n\nBaca juga: Isi Bahan Bakar, Lebih Baik Pakai Nominal Rupiah atau Liter?\n\nDOK. PT HMSI Mekanik Hino sedang servis perawatan truk Mekanik Hino sedang servis perawatan truk\n\n“Walaupun Hino mengirim kendaraan dalam bentuk landasan dan diserahkan ke diler, kami berharap Hino tetap bertanggung jawab dalam menjamin bahwa kendaraan Hino sudah tidak ada lagi yang dibangun secara over dimensi,” kata Budi.\n\nPasalnya, berdasarkan temuan Dirjen Hubdat di karoseri di area Jawa Timur, masih ditemukan kendaraan yang dibangun secara over dimension. Jadi gunakan kelebihan dari truk untuk menjamin keselamatan, bukan dibuat ODOL.',
           'GRESIK, KOMPAS.com - Kantor Pengawasan dan Pelayanan Bea Cukai (KPPBC) Gresik menggagalkan penyelundupan kapal Roro (Roll On-Roll Off) yang dilakukan oleh salah satu perusahaan penyeberangan di Surabaya.\n\nKepala KPPBC Gresik Bier Budi Kismuljanto mengatakan, keberhasilan pengungkapan kasus ini berkat kerja sama dengan Kantor Syahbandar dan Otoritas Pelabuhan (KSOP) Gresik dan juga Kejaksaan Negeri (Kejari) Gresik.\n\nAdapun kapal bekas yang diberinama Revo 8 buatan tahun 1989 itu, diselundupkan oleh PT Trimitra Samudra dari Jepang pada Bulan Maret 2020 lalu.\n\nBaca juga: Gagalkan Penyelundupan 22.230 Benur ke Singapura, Kepala BKIPM: Kami Tidak Main-main!\n\nBier mengaku, awal mula pihaknya mendapatkan informasi ada kapal impor masuk ke wilayah Gresik melalui KSOP Gresik.\n\nOleh petugas Bea Cukai Gresik, informasi tersebut kemudian ditindaklanjuti dengan melakukan penyisiran dan ditemukan kapal sedang docking di galangan PT Indonesia Marina Shipyard (IMS).\n\n"Setelah mengetahui keberadaan kapal, petugas kami mulai melakukan penyelidikan dan konfirmasi dokumen kapal," ujar Bier kepada media, Selasa (13/4/2021).\n\nBaca juga: KKP Gagalkan Penyelundupan 54,9 Ton Ikan Patin Senilai Rp 2,7 Miliar\n\nPenyidik dari Bea Cukai Gresik kemudian melakukan pendalaman kasus, dan mendapati banyak dokumen yang dimanipulasi oleh perusahaan pelayaran. Di antaranya, tahun pembuatan kapal yang telah diubah dari tahun 1989 menjadi 2007 serta berat kapal dari 627 GT (Gross Tonnage) dimanipulasi menjadi 1.007 GT.\n\nMenurut Bier, manipulasi yang dilakukan telah melanggar Peraturan Menteri Perdagangan (Permendag) Nomor 118 Tahun 2018, tentang Ketentuan Impor Barang Modal Dalam Keadaan Tidak Baru.\n\n“Dalam aturan Permendag itu diatur, kapal yang boleh dilakukan impor berusia maksimal 20 tahun dan memiliki berat 1.000 ton. Jika itu dilanggar, pelakunya bisa dikenakan sanksi denda hingga pidana," ucap Bier.\n\nSementara Kepala Kejaksaan Negeri Gresik Heru Winoto menambahkan, penyidikan kasus ini membutuhkan waktu selama satu tahun. Ini karena pihak Bea Cukai Gresik membutuhkan tambahan barang bukti untuk menjerat beberapa pihak serta melakukan koordinasi dengan atase perwakilan Kementrian keuangan yang berada di Jepang.\n\n“Saat kami menyidik kasus ini, sempat ada upaya intervensi dari beberapa pihak. Namun kami tetap lurus hingga bisa menjerat tersangka, Direktur PT TS berinisial JAK dan kasus ini siap untuk dibawa ke pengadilan,” kata Heru.\n\nAdapun Kepala KSOP Gresik Capt Dwi Yanto, mengapreasiasi kecepatan Bea Cukai Gresik dalam menggagalkan penyelundupan kapal Roro, yang dinilai menyelamatkan masyarakat pengguna kapal Roro dari ancaman bahaya di laut.']

title = ['Kemenhub Minta Hino Ikut Cegah Praktik Truk ODOL',
         'Bea Cukai Gagalkan Penyelundupan Kapal di Gresik']

keyword = ['diselundupkan', 'penyelundupan', 'penyelundupan kapal', 'kemenhub']
```

I'm sorry for long article :)

I want to create function that match **article** and **title** with keyword and return that results only the **keyword.**

My code is:

```
from itertools import compress
ab = []
for t in article:
  if len(list(compress(keyword, (f in t.lower() for f in keyword)))) == 0:
    for i in title:
      ab = list(compress(keyword, (f in i.lower() for f in keyword)))
  else:
    ab.append(list(compress(keyword, (f in t.lower() for f in keyword))))
```

and the output I get is:

```
['penyelundupan','penyelundupan kapal',['diselundupkan', 'penyelundupan', 'penyelundupan kapal']]
```

But I want the result as below

```
['kemenhub',['diselundupkan', 'penyelundupan', 'penyelundupan kapal']]
```

Anyone who can help me would be very appreciated. Big Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit unclear to me what you are trying to achieve, but the way I interpret the question is that you want to iterate over the articles in `article`, check if any of the keywords appear in the article and append those keywords to `ab`, or, if none of the keywords appear in the article, extend `ab` with any keywords that appear in the corresponding title of the article. If this is the correct interpretation, then you could do something like this:

```
article = ['JAKARTA, KOMPAS.com – PT Hino Motors Sales Indonesia (HMSI) merilis truk baru yaitu FLX260 JW, Selasa (6/4/2021). Truk ini memiliki konfigurasi sumbu 8x2 atau biasa disebut dengan trinton.\n\nMemiliki empat sumbu roda, tentu truk terbaru Hino ini bisa mengangkut beban yang besar, FLX260 JW memiliki GVW 32 ton. Namun perlu diperhatikan, jangan sampai truk terbaru ini malah dijadikan truk yang Over Dimension Over Loading (ODOL).\n\nDirektur Jenderal Perhubugan Darat Kemeterian Perhubungan Budi Setiadi mengatakan, Hino meluncurkan kendaraan yang dikatakan memiliki kekuatan lebih tapi efisien. Ini menjadi suatu tantangan bagi karoseri.\n\nBaca juga: Masalah Lain Truk ODOL Indonesia, Ditolak Masuk Negara Tetangga\n\nKOMPAS.com/STANLY RAVEL Ilustrasi truk ODOL di jalan tol. KOMPAS.com/STANLY RAVEL Ilustrasi truk ODOL di jalan tol.\n\n“Karena begitu bicara kekuatan, dia (pembeli) mengira bisa dipasang apa saja. Hal ini dikarenakan pembeli didominasi orang yang enerjik dan penuh inovasi dan kreasi. Jangan sampai kreasi mereka menciptakan truk-truk ODOL baru,” ucap Budi dalam acara peluncuran produk terbaru Hino beberapa waktu lalu.\n\nBudi berharap, ke depan, tidak ada lagi karoseri yang membuat truk over dimension untuk mengangkut beban berlebih (over loading). Selain itu juga berharap dari Hino untuk sama-sama menjaga Indonesia bebas truk ODOL.\n\nBaca juga: Isi Bahan Bakar, Lebih Baik Pakai Nominal Rupiah atau Liter?\n\nDOK. PT HMSI Mekanik Hino sedang servis perawatan truk Mekanik Hino sedang servis perawatan truk\n\n“Walaupun Hino mengirim kendaraan dalam bentuk landasan dan diserahkan ke diler, kami berharap Hino tetap bertanggung jawab dalam menjamin bahwa kendaraan Hino sudah tidak ada lagi yang dibangun secara over dimensi,” kata Budi.\n\nPasalnya, berdasarkan temuan Dirjen Hubdat di karoseri di area Jawa Timur, masih ditemukan kendaraan yang dibangun secara over dimension. Jadi gunakan kelebihan dari truk untuk menjamin keselamatan, bukan dibuat ODOL.',
           'GRESIK, KOMPAS.com - Kantor Pengawasan dan Pelayanan Bea Cukai (KPPBC) Gresik menggagalkan penyelundupan kapal Roro (Roll On-Roll Off) yang dilakukan oleh salah satu perusahaan penyeberangan di Surabaya.\n\nKepala KPPBC Gresik Bier Budi Kismuljanto mengatakan, keberhasilan pengungkapan kasus ini berkat kerja sama dengan Kantor Syahbandar dan Otoritas Pelabuhan (KSOP) Gresik dan juga Kejaksaan Negeri (Kejari) Gresik.\n\nAdapun kapal bekas yang diberinama Revo 8 buatan tahun 1989 itu, diselundupkan oleh PT Trimitra Samudra dari Jepang pada Bulan Maret 2020 lalu.\n\nBaca juga: Gagalkan Penyelundupan 22.230 Benur ke Singapura, Kepala BKIPM: Kami Tidak Main-main!\n\nBier mengaku, awal mula pihaknya mendapatkan informasi ada kapal impor masuk ke wilayah Gresik melalui KSOP Gresik.\n\nOleh petugas Bea Cukai Gresik, informasi tersebut kemudian ditindaklanjuti dengan melakukan penyisiran dan ditemukan kapal sedang docking di galangan PT Indonesia Marina Shipyard (IMS).\n\n"Setelah mengetahui keberadaan kapal, petugas kami mulai melakukan penyelidikan dan konfirmasi dokumen kapal," ujar Bier kepada media, Selasa (13/4/2021).\n\nBaca juga: KKP Gagalkan Penyelundupan 54,9 Ton Ikan Patin Senilai Rp 2,7 Miliar\n\nPenyidik dari Bea Cukai Gresik kemudian melakukan pendalaman kasus, dan mendapati banyak dokumen yang dimanipulasi oleh perusahaan pelayaran. Di antaranya, tahun pembuatan kapal yang telah diubah dari tahun 1989 menjadi 2007 serta berat kapal dari 627 GT (Gross Tonnage) dimanipulasi menjadi 1.007 GT.\n\nMenurut Bier, manipulasi yang dilakukan telah melanggar Peraturan Menteri Perdagangan (Permendag) Nomor 118 Tahun 2018, tentang Ketentuan Impor Barang Modal Dalam Keadaan Tidak Baru.\n\n“Dalam aturan Permendag itu diatur, kapal yang boleh dilakukan impor berusia maksimal 20 tahun dan memiliki berat 1.000 ton. Jika itu dilanggar, pelakunya bisa dikenakan sanksi denda hingga pidana," ucap Bier.\n\nSementara Kepala Kejaksaan Negeri Gresik Heru Winoto menambahkan, penyidikan kasus ini membutuhkan waktu selama satu tahun. Ini karena pihak Bea Cukai Gresik membutuhkan tambahan barang bukti untuk menjerat beberapa pihak serta melakukan koordinasi dengan atase perwakilan Kementrian keuangan yang berada di Jepang.\n\n“Saat kami menyidik kasus ini, sempat ada upaya intervensi dari beberapa pihak. Namun kami tetap lurus hingga bisa menjerat tersangka, Direktur PT TS berinisial JAK dan kasus ini siap untuk dibawa ke pengadilan,” kata Heru.\n\nAdapun Kepala KSOP Gresik Capt Dwi Yanto, mengapreasiasi kecepatan Bea Cukai Gresik dalam menggagalkan penyelundupan kapal Roro, yang dinilai menyelamatkan masyarakat pengguna kapal Roro dari ancaman bahaya di laut.']

title = ['Kemenhub Minta Hino Ikut Cegah Praktik Truk ODOL',
         'Bea Cukai Gagalkan Penyelundupan Kapal di Gresik']

keyword = ['diselundupkan', 'penyelundupan', 'penyelundupan kapal', 'kemenhub']

result = []
for aa, tt in zip(article, title):
    kw_list = [kw for kw in keyword if kw in aa.lower()]
    if kw_list:
        result.append(kw_list)
    else:
        result.extend([kw for kw in keyword if kw in tt.lower()])

print(result)

# output: ['kemenhub', ['diselundupkan', 'penyelundupan', 'penyelundupan kapal']]
```

Comment: You're interpretation is right, this is exactly what I want. big thanks bro.